# NumberFormatException when constructing BigInteger from result of Math.pow

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to work with some larger integer values but I'm having some issues initializing my BigInteger variable. I've been doing:

```
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("" + (Math.pow(2, n)));
```

Where n is some number in the 100s, but this is throwing a NumberFormatException. I don't think I can use BigInteger,Valueof() because that takes a long which i don't believe is big enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Perform the operation with [`BigInteger.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int))

Comment: Pow returns a double

Comment: BigInteger if used from BigInteger.

Answer (score 7):

One way or another [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) returns a value of type `double` which will be formatted with a decimal separator. `BigInteger` cannot accept decimal values.

> **Throws:**
>     `NumberFormatException` - val is not a valid representation of a `BigInteger`.

Just use the [`pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)) method provided by `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger x = BigInteger.TWO.pow(n);
```

Comment: Interestingly, for large `n`, `BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(n)` appears to be about twice as fast as `BigInteger.TWO.pow(n)`

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle: well, that makes a lot of sense. `shiftLeft()` can very efficiently shift, while `pow()` must really *calculate* the power using several multiplications. Actually, I'd expected `shiftLeft()` to be much faster than what you found, even for relatively "small" values of `n`.

Comment: As there is no BigInteger.TWO (AFAIK), I modified your answer a little.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Since 9, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#TWO

Comment: @Savior: ah, didn't try 9 yet.